# Android: Prevent GPS from stopping

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

I have an issue with the GPS on Android. I am using the onStatusChanged(int status) with the GPSListener to read the status of the GPS. However, I notice that after some point, the GPS stops since the status returns:

GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED

How can I prevent the GPS from stopping at all? (Eventually I will stop it manually, but having it on when needed is very crucial)

Comment: How is GPS started (in a Service?) What device are you using? From what I know, it is not supposed to stop, unless there is a malfunction in the lower layers.

Comment: I am using HTC Desire, and I think it is stopping because of battery saving mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your LocationListener in a Service it will be stopped eventually unless you set the wake lock. This has nothing to do with the GPS itself.

To acquire and release the wake lock I use the following code in my service:

```
/**
 * Acquire a wake lock.
 * Ensure the CPU remains on and the screen is at least dim.
 */
private void aquireWakeLock() {
    final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    this.wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    this.wakeLock.acquire();
    if( DEBUG )
        Log.d( TAG, "Wake lock aquired:" + this.wakeLock);
}

/**
 * Release the wake lock.
 */
private void releaseWakeLock() {
    if( this.wakeLock == null )
        return;
    this.wakeLock.release();
    this.wakeLock = null;
    if( DEBUG )
        Log.d( TAG, "Wake lock release");
}
```

The methods are called in onCreate() resp. onDestroy().